# Nodejs Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, strategy-pattern

I am doing  a nodejs web program and i need a local authentication, google and facebook. For google and facebook i dont have already a dns to return successful. 
When i do a local authentication de server keep thinking and says they don’t have response. 
That's my server.js: (please help me )

```
var express = require('express'),
flash = require('connect-flash')
exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
logger = require('morgan'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
session = require('express-session'),
passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
mongoose = require('mongoose');
GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy,
FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
util = require('util')
SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "944091472291356"
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = [removed];
User = require('./models/user.js');
login = require('./views/layouts/userlogin');
signin = require('./views/signin');
var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
 auth = require('basic-auth');
mysql = require('mysql')


//Creating connection to data base
var config = require('./config.js'), //config file contains all tokens and other private info
funct = require('./functions.js'), //funct file contains our helper functions for our Passport and database work
app = express();
//Base de dados mongo
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabase", function(err, db){
if( !err ){
console.log("Ligado ao servidor mongoDB");
} else console.log(err);
});

UserSchema = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
if (err) return cb(err);
cb(null, isMatch);
});
};


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserDetail = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String
}, {
collection: 'userInfo'

});

var ricardo = new User ({
username : 'ricardo',
password : 'rolo',
hasCreditCookie: true
});


var UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail);
//We will be creating these two files shortly
var config = require('./config.js'), //config file contains all tokens and other private info
funct = require('./functions.js'); //funct file contains our helper functions for our Passport and database work
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true }
});
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;
// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
if (err) return next(err);
// hash the password using our new salt
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
if (err) return next(err);
// override the cleartext password with the hashed one
user.password = hash;
next();
});
});
});
function findById(id, fn) {
var idx = id - 1;
if (users[idx]) {
fn(null, users[idx]);
} else {
fn(new Error('User ' + id + ' does not exist'));
}
}
function findByUsername(username, fn) {
for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
var user = users[i];
if (user.username === username) {
return fn(null, user);
}
}
return fn(null, null);
}
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail);
//new schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserDetail = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String
}, {
collection: 'userInfo'
});

////////////////////////////////Local - PASSPORT by:zezão xD

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
   connection.query("select * from BdClientes.Users where username='"+username+"'     ",function(err,user){
    if(err)
    {
        return done(err);           
    }
    if(!user)
    {
        return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect user name'});           
    }
    if(user.password != password)
    {
       return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect password'});
    }

    return done(null,user);     

   });
}
));
app.post('/home', passport.authenticate('signin',{successRedirect: '/home', failureRedirect: '/signin', failureFlash: true }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

// passport/signin.js
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
    username : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    // verifica no mongo se o nome de usuário existe ou não
    User.findOne({ 'username' :  username },
      function(err, username) {
        // Em caso de erro, retorne usando o método done
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        // Nome de usuário não existe, logar o erro & redirecione de volta
        if (!user){
          console.log('Usuário não encontrado para usuário '+username);
          return done(null, false,
                req.flash('message', 'Usuário não encontrado.'));
        }
        // Usuário existe mas a senha está errada, logar o erro
        if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
          console.log('Senha Inválida');
          return done(null, false,
              req.flash('message', 'Senha Inválida'));
        }
        // Tanto usuário e senha estão corretos, retorna usuário através
        // do método done, e, agora, será considerado um sucesso
        return done(null, user);
      }
    );
}));



//LOCAL signin
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField : 'username',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
process.nextTick(function() {
User.findOne({ 'local.username' : username }, function(err, user) {
if (err)
return done(err);
if (user) {
return done(null, false, req.flash('signinMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
} else {
// if there is no user with that email
// create the user
var newUser = new User();
// set the user's local credentials
newUser.local.email = email;
newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
if (err)
throw err;
return done(null, newUser);
});
}
});
});
process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
}));



// Use the LocalStrategy within Passport to register/"signin" users.
passport.use('signin', new LocalStrategy(
{passReqToCallback : true}, //allows us to pass back the request to the callback
function(req, username, password, done) {
funct.signin(username, password)
.then(function (user) {
if (user) {
console.log("REGISTERED: " + user.username);
req.session.success = 'You are successfully registered and logged in ' + user.username + '!';
done(null, user);
}
if (!user) {
console.log("COULD NOT REGISTER");
req.session.error = 'That username is already in use, please try a different one.'; //inform user could not log them in
done(null, user);
}
})
.fail(function (err){
console.log(err.body);
});
}
));
// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
req.session.error = 'Please sign in!';
res.redirect('/signin');
}
////FACEBOOK PASSPORT
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
process.nextTick(function () {
return done(null, profile);
});
}
));
//GOOGLE
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
returnURL : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/google',
realm: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
},
function(identifier, profile, done) {
User.findOrCreate({ openId: identifier }, function(err, user) {
done(err, user);
});
}
));
////////////////////////////////////////EXPRESS
// Configure Express
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(session({secret: 'supernova', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// Configure express to use handlebars templates
var hbs = exphbs.create({
defaultLayout: 'main', //we will be creating this layout shortly
});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);//handlebars templates
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');//
//// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');//EJS templates
//app.use(app.mountpath);
// Session-persisted message middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next){
var err = req.session.error,
msg = req.session.notice,
success = req.session.success;
delete req.session.error;
delete req.session.success;
delete req.session.notice;
if (err) res.locals.error = err;
if (msg) res.locals.notice = msg;
if (success) res.locals.success = success;
next();
});
//Requerido para o passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'eutentoetento' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session




///////////////////////////////////////////ROUTES
//displays our homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('./home', {user: req.user});
});
//login//
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('error') });
});
//sends the request through our local login/signin strategy, and if successful takes user to homepage, otherwise returns then to signin page
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate('home', function(err, user, info) {

   // Error Check
   if(err) { return next(err);
 }
   // Json Response reflecting authentication status
   if(!user) { 
      return res.send({success:false, message: 'authentication failed '})
   }
   // Success
   return res.send({succes:true, message: 'authentication succeeded'}) 
  })
})



//SIGNIN//
app.get('/signin', function(req, res){
res.render('signin', { message: req.flash('signinMessage') });;
});
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
failureRedirect : '/signin', // redirect back to the signin page if there is an error
failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
//PROFILE
app.get('profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
res.render('profile', {
user: req.user // tira o user da sessao e passa para o template
});
});
//LOGOUT
//logs user out of site, deleting them from the session, and returns to homepage
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
var name = req.user.username;
console.log("LOGGIN OUT " + req.user.username)
req.logout();
res.redirect('/');
req.session.notice = "You have successfully been logged out " + name + "!";
});
//FB
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
req.logout();
res.redirect('/');
});
<pre>
//google routes//
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
app.get('/auth/google/return',
passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',
failureRedirect: '/login' }));
// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
if (req.isAuthenticated())
return next();
// if they aren't redirect them to the home page
res.redirect('/');
}
//////////////////////////////////LAUCH
//===============PORT=================
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000; //select your port or let it pull from your .env file
app.listen(port);
console.log("listening on " + port + "!");
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Do you really intend to post your Facebook developer credentials here?

Comment: Way too much code here. Only post the relevant code and narrow down the scope of your question.

Comment: You should use a tool like ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to register a public domain with facebook to set a callback uri during development.

Comment: why he needs that @Yousef, he can define the google login callback to http://localhost:whatEver .. I just did it (using passport).

Comment: @ricardo I recommend you invalidate your facebook credentials as soon as possible. Your APP_SECRET is still viewable in the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already using [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) for local authentication, you should take a look at its plugins (called Strategies) to connect to different services using OAuth or OpenID, including [Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook), [Twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter), and [Google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth).  [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) is a pretty good tutorial ([with updates for express 4.0](https://scotch.io/tutorials/upgrading-our-easy-node-authentication-series-to-expressjs-4-0)) that explains how to do those types of authentication.

Also, I would recommend putting those schemas in their own files, for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Node has a great OAuth2 package using "googleapis" that does almost all the authentication for you (I used it for accessing my calendar, but you can use it for other things too).

use it like so:

```
var google = require('googleapis');<br/>
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
```

and then:

```
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2("clientID", "client_secret", "redirectURL");
```

You can get your `clientid` and `client_secret` from your google account (I think you need a developer account which is free). The redirect url is where you want to go after the authentication.

Check out their npm page for more details. I'm sure there is something similar for facebook. Using this library makes everything look like google too, so you don't look like you are hacking something. You might also want to read up on oauth2 since that is the latest standard and most web services support it.